# Android autocomplete not working

Tags: android, autocomplete

I followed [this tutorial from the Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html) site. But, the auto complete doesnt work. Is there something missing? Is there a better tutorial i can use (one that actually works)?

Comment: would you please explain what is *doesn't work* means, what exactly the problem is, at what step are you stuck, which un-expected behaviour it is showing..

Comment: What did you try? how do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: When I run it and type in a letter(s), the suggest/autocomplete list doesnt show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example with source code here:
http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/auto-complete-text-view-android.html

Check it out and see if you still get the problem.  If you do not then you probably missed something from tutorial you are following initially.

Kind regards,
Bo

Comment: thanks, i changed `R.layout.list_item` to `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` and it worked. thats the only difference between the two tutorials.